# Store a class module as a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, events

I wrote some code in a `class module` and `userform_initialize_event`. All are okay. But when I Dim the new class module and applies in the initialize event it says that variable not defined.
Here is my code -

```
Dim Buttons() As New BtnClass

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim ButtonCount As Integer
    Dim ctl As Control
    '   Create the Button objects
    ButtonCount = 0
    
    For Each ctl In fmHover.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            ButtonCount = ButtonCount + 1
            ReDim Preserve Buttons(1 To ButtonCount)
            Set Buttons(ButtonCount).ButtonGroup = ctl
        End If
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

If I Dim the Buttons inside the event it does not throws any error and the code also don't works. I searched in a lot of place. Every one Dim the new class before the Initialize event. So, why my one doesn't work? Kindly suggest where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to define your dynamic array in separate common module.

Comment: Duplicate of [Store a class module as a variable in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852178/store-a-class-module-as-a-variable-in-vba/72854260#72854260) on SO.